# Get function to fire with default values?

Tags: jquery

I currently have a user calculator where numbers are entered and several calculations are run. Currently the function fires on keyup, how can I get it to fire when the original default value is there?

Also the input field is a number field, if you click the up/down arrows to increase the number the function doesn't fire because I'm not keying anything in, how can I get that to fire the function as well?

**So in essence, I want the function to fire via 3 different ways - on keyup, on load and on change (via the browser arrows for a number input).**

```
<input type="number" name="perweek" id="per_week" value="<?php echo the_sub_field('default_value'); ?>">
```

Here's the jquery:

```
$('#per_week').keyup(function(){
        var calcString = '';
        var result = 0;

        var calcStringq = '';
        var resultq = 0;

        var userInput = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);

        if(!isNaN(userInput)) {
            for(var i = 0; i < calculations.length; i++) {

                calcString = userInput + calculations[i];
                result = eval(calcString);
                $('#result-' + i).text(result);

            }

            for (var x in calculationsq) {
                calcStringq = $('#result-' + x).text() + calculationsq[x];
                resultq = eval(calcStringq);
                $('#result-q-' + x).text(resultq);

            }   
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per this sentence `So in essence, I want the function to fire via 3 different ways - on keyup, on load and on change (via the browser arrows for a number input).`

Firstly via those arrows means suggest you to use `input` event.

Here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yitif/1/edit)
this should work by using on listener

```
$('#per_week').on('keyup input', function(){
.............
});
```

**Option 1** Name the function and pass it in the as a callback in all required events.

```
    function calculator(){
            var calcString = '';
            var result = 0;

            var calcStringq = '';
            var resultq = 0;

            var userInput = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);

            if(!isNaN(userInput)) {
                for(var i = 0; i < calculations.length; i++) {

                    calcString = userInput + calculations[i];
                    result = eval(calcString);
                    $('#result-' + i).text(result);

                }

                for (var x in calculationsq) {
                    calcStringq = $('#result-' + x).text() + calculationsq[x];
                    resultq = eval(calcStringq);
                    $('#result-q-' + x).text(resultq);

                }   
            }


$('#per_week').keyup(calculator);
$('#per_week').change(calculator);
$('#per_week').input(calculator);
//for onload
$(document).ready(function(){
   calculator();
})
```

**option 2** Trigger the keyup event wherever you need to function to get executed

```
     $('#per_week').keyup(function(){
            var calcString = '';
            var result = 0;

            var calcStringq = '';
            var resultq = 0;

            var userInput = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);

            if(!isNaN(userInput)) {
                for(var i = 0; i < calculations.length; i++) {

                    calcString = userInput + calculations[i];
                    result = eval(calcString);
                    $('#result-' + i).text(result);

                }

                for (var x in calculationsq) {
                    calcStringq = $('#result-' + x).text() + calculationsq[x];
                    resultq = eval(calcStringq);
                    $('#result-q-' + x).text(resultq);

                }   
            }

        });
    $('#per_week').change(function(event){
      $(this).trigger('keyup');
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(this).trigger('keyup');
   });
```

Comment: Ok I have the keyup and change working via option 2, the only thing I can't get to work is the default value calculating.

Comment: did you try input event??

Comment: BTW default value means after returning from some new value??

Comment: by your mean, $(function(){}) can work, for the default value is from php function, so you can calculate the default value by your php code, orelse you can trigger onfocus event in $(function(){})

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#per_week').on('change', function() {
     // change event
 }).on('keydown', function(e) {
     if(e.which == 38) { // up key
         //up key event
     }
     else if(e.which == 40) {
         // down key event;
     }
 });
```

but load event is confused me? $(function(){ ... }); 
or $('#per_week').on('focus', function(){...}); ?